# How to get MQTT client id in Websphere AS?

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, mqtt

My application receives MQTT messages via JMS on a Websphere AS. The MQTT endpoint is a Websphere MQ.

Is there any way to identify the sender of the message (the sending device, not Websphere MQ ;-) )? I could not find a matching field in the jms message header...

Answer (score 1):

When creating the MQTT channel there are options to use either the MQTT Client ID or the Username for authorization checks.  If the channel is configured to use JAAS and the option to use the Username is selected, I *believe* the `MQMD.UserID` inherits the Username.  I don't have JAAS authentication configured but when I get some time later I'll test it and update.

I was able to test the option that uses the ClientID for authorization and it does *not* result in the client ID ending up in the `MQMD.UserID` field.

Since identity propagation is a common requirement, I'd suggest raising a [Request For Enhancement](http://ibm.co/IBMRFE) (RFE) stating that either Client ID or Username should propagate to the `MQMD.UserID`, depending onthe channel setting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On Wireshark we can see the ID information is part of the message but unfortunately we are not getting any mq header information inside our MDB. We are in concact with your colleagues in UK.

Comment: I'm lobbying for ID propagation in all the components supporting MQTT.  It would help me to put customer names, specific requirements and use cases to the request. Please email me at the contact info on my profile page with details or add me to copy on the email thread.  Thanks!